# MVC Change Row color based on value from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, colors, row

I have those 2 columns and I want to put the row where's the travel consultant = Username1 with green color on the letters and username2 with red color on the letters.
How can I do this ?

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered tablesModel">
    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th data-field="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Travel_Consultant)" data-sortable="true">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Travel_Consultant)
            </th>

            @*scope1, scope2*@

            <th data-field="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)">
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td data-field="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Travel_Consultant)" data-sortable="true">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Travel_Consultant)
                </td>
                <td data-field="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </td>

            <td style="text-align:center;">
            <button onclick="createOrEdit(@item.ExtraJobsID)" type="button" class="btn-xs buttongreenpt">
            <i class="fa fa-edit fa-20px"></i>
            </button>
            </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In foreach loop

```
if(consultant = Username1)
assign class Green to that row
.Green{color: green;}


else if(consultant = Username1)
assign class Red to that row
.Red{color: red;}
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply code inside your view, try something like this inside your @foreach:

```
          <tr>
            @if (model.Travel_Consultant == "Username1")
            {
            <td data-field="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Travel_Consultant)" 
            data-sortable="true" style="color: red">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Travel_Consultant, new { @style = 
             "color:green;" })
            </td>

             }
             else if(model.Travel_Consultant == "username2")
             {
            <td data-field="@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description, new { @style = 
                "color:red;" })
            </td>

             }

        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <button onclick="createOrEdit(@item.ExtraJobsID)" type="button" class="btn-xs buttongreenpt">
                <i class="fa fa-edit fa-20px"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
```